# How to add Two Columns (Date/Time) Together in Tableau

Tags: datetime, tableau-api, addition

I have a dataset which was imported from Excel to Tableau.   In Excel the data is listed as "8:15:00 AM".  When it's imported into Tableau it's now Date & Time as "12/30/1899 10:45:00 AM".

What I'm trying to perform is an addition problem between two date & time columns. An example being:
Sleep: 12/30/1899 10:45:00
Eating: 12/30/1899 00:45:00

Sleep + Eating which should yield 10:40 + 00:45 = 11:30

After much googling and video watching, I have not found a solution.

Comment: Do the values in your data represents date-times (a point in time) or intervals (a duration of time)? Getting that detail straight is important.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a calculated [as such](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/combining-a-date-and-a-time-field) should solve the problem:

```
DATEADD(
'hour', DATEPART('hour', [Eating]), DATEADD(
'minute', DATEPART('minute', [Eating]), DATEADD(
'second', DATEPART('second', [Eating]), [Sleep])))
```

From there, the time display of the field can be adjusted as necessary:

Right-click field name > Default Properties > Date Format

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to find an answer on your own please post it and give the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by creating three calculated fields. Lets call one of the calculated field [hours] and another one [minutes]. A third field  will use the values from [hours] and [minutes] in order to properly display the results. Let's call this third field [Sleep + Eating].

To create [hours]:

```
//[hours] calculated field
DATEPART('hour', [Sleep])+ DATEPART('hour', [Eating])
```

To create [minutes]:

```
 //[hours] calculated field
    DATEPART('minute', [Sleep])+DATEPART('minute', [Eating])
```

At this point [hours] and [minutes] are just the sums of the integer values from [Sleep] and [Eating]. To display these sums  in the format  you have requested, you'll need to have a third calculated field that concatenates hours and the minutes, and is also able to handle a situations where the minutes add up to more than 60, or when the minutes add up to less then 10.[Sleep + Eating] calculated field will achieve this.

Here is the [Sleep + Eating] calculated field:

```
//[Sleep + Eating] calculated field
IF  [minutes]< 10  THEN STR([hours])+":0"+STR([minutes])
ELSEIF [minutes]< 60 THEN STR([hours])+":"+STR([minutes])
ELSEIF [minutes]>= 70 THEN STR([hours]+1)+":"+STR([minutes]-60)
ELSE STR([hours]+1)+":0"+STR([minutes]-60)
END
```

Other solutions that try to treat your data like a date field (See @Daniel Sims answer) could be problematic if the hours sum to greater than 23, the result will add a day. For example, lets say you had these values in Excel:

[image: 14:45:00 Eating: 12/30/1899 14:45:00]

If you use my solution, the result will be 25:02. If you use @Daniel Sims answer, the result would be 12/31/1899 1:02 :00 AM, which I don't think is what you want.